# Unable to play local inline audio in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, html5-audio

I'm unable to play a local audio WAV file in my Rhomobile UIWebView app. The audio control just displays "Error". Using an HTTPS web link works fine with the same file.

```
<audio id="old_fence_audio" src="/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5D1E44F5-831A-47D2-9C3C-80B54E7A5B87/data/Containers/Data/Application/8061C421-9CD5-4F29-B300-F4DD90F8D64E/Documents/db/db-files/fence_audio_1504734753.wav" controls="" controlslist="nodownload" width="100%" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"></audio>
```

I have also tried adding file: or file:// in front of the path.

I'm loading the UIWebView with these settings:

```
- (void)loadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    [webview setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
    self.webview.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
    [webview loadRequest:request];
}
```

I'm using iOS SDK 10.3.